# How to Store Array Value From Select2 JS in Laravel

Tags: laravel, jquery-select2

I'm using MySQL Database. I have select2 js with multiple value
Here is my code

My Blade View And JS

```
<input type="text" class="form-control tools_id" name="tools_id[]" multiple/>
```

```
var $tools_id = jQuery('.tools_id');
$tools_id.select2({
    multiple: true,
    placeholder: 'Tools',
    ajax: {
        url: 'sample/gettools',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (term, page) {
            return {
                q: term, //search term
            };
        },
        results: function (data) {
            return {
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        text: item.tools,
                        id: item.tools_id
                    }
                })
            };
        },
        cache: true
    }
});
```

My Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Sample extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public $incrementing = false;

    protected $table = 'lab_sample';

    protected $casts = [
        'tools_id' => 'array'
    ];

    protected $fillable = ['name','summary','tools_id'];
}
```

My Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $sample = Sample::create([
        'name'     => $request->name,
        'summary'  => $request->summary,
        'tools_id' => $request->input('tools_id'),
    ]);

    return Response::json($sample);
}
```

My code was successfully save the data, but the problem is when i selected more than one value/tags, it saved the array value (tools_id) like this

```
["20,21"]
```

Where it supposed to be like this

```
["20","21"]
```

Comment: to store array of values, you need to format the table column as 'json'

Comment: Maybe you could use a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-a-mutator) to properly format the value.